# Fetch data using a unique token

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fetch some json data from an api using a curl token i got from the company but i don't know why this does not fetch the data

```
var token = 'c5de7ee89c1925924dbf0cfd0087b9642fb8cd5c';
$.ajax({
    url: "https://formhub.org/api/v1/data/north_ghana/8379",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + token); 
    },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Cannot get data");
    }
});
```

This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Vx52j/3/

Comment: You are not sending your token, syntax should be `xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + token);`.

Comment: I had that earlier but still nothing.

Comment: Seems that your (or their) authentication is not working... `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)`

Comment: Anyways, that does not look like a BasicAuth token [which is the Base64 encoding of `username:password`], but like a SHA1 hash of it.

Comment: Yes,i did tell them that but they insist i have to use the token.The original was a curl request.

Comment: @user3275727 Then why not ask them why it doesn't work? It's a bit like stabbing in the dark here, really.

Comment: I have asked like 2 times already,same answer,so...